# Catch all inputs by class in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following (there can be any number of images but showing 2 here). How do I iterate through the inputs in javascript?

```
<div id="uploaded_images">
    <div class="uploaded_image">
        <input name="uploaded_image_name[]" type="hidden" value="pic1.jpg"> 
        <img src="uploads/pic1.jpg"> 
    </div>
    <div class="uploaded_image">
        <input name="uploaded_image_name[]" type="hidden" value="pic2.jpg"> 
        <img src="uploads/pic2.jpg"> 
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried:

```
var photos = document.getElementsByClassName("uploaded_image_name");
for (var photoCount = 0; photoCount < photos.length; photoCount++) {
  $photoName = photos.item(photoCount);
}
```

and

```
var photos = document.querySelectorAll('[class^="uploaded_image_name"]')
```

but can't get it to work.

Comment: Your selectors are wrong. No elements have a class starting with `uploaded_image_name`. They have those as `name` attributes, but not class attributes. I'd use `document.querySelectorAll('.uploaded_image input')`

Comment: What a dope I am. Thanks.